# Get device ID from current capture

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I'm using OpenCV to get some video frames. This is how the camera capture is initialised:

```
VideoCapture capture;
capture.open(0);  //Read from camera #0
```

If I wanted to switch to different camera, I'd do this:

```
capture.release();  //Release the stream
capture.open(1);    //Open different stream
```

Imagine you had a few cameras connected to your computer and you wanted to loop through them using two buttons <kbd>Previous camera</kbd> and <kbd>Next camera</kbd>. Without saving the current camera ID to a variable, I need to get the actual value from the `VideoCapture` object.
So is there a way how to **find out** the **id of currently used device**?

Pseudocode:

```
int current = capture.deviceId;
capture.release();
capture.open(current++);
```

Comment: Seems like that's impossible. Can you just keep index of current camera in static variable?

Comment: If there will be no other way, I will surely use the global variable - And I actually did so, as a temporary solution. But I see no point in storing the same information in two places, so I'm trying to extract it from `VideoCapture` instance.

Comment: Hi Are you find solution for this, Suggest me to how to connect web cameras by their instant id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is there a way how to find out the id of currently used device?

There's no way to do this because class `VideoCapture` doesn't contain such variable or method. It actually contains `protected` pointer to `CvCapture` (take a look at `highgui.h`) so you could try to play with it but you don't have access to this field.